# join string on vba Fibonacci seq

Tags: excel, vba

I'm tring to write the first 20 values of Fibonacci sequence at A1 cell
the output should be 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55

1. I have error when I'm trying to add the numbers to the string.
2. how can I put the result in A1 cell?

here is my attempt:

```
Sub Looping()

Series = 0
newVar = 1

For x = 1 To 20
  Series = Series + newVar
  newVar = Series - newVar
  Series=Series& newVar&","
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: [Fibonacci java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/13flow/Fibonacci.java.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Looping()

    series = "1"
    oldvar = 1
    newvar = 1


    For x = 1 To 20

      series = Series & "," & newvar
      newvar = oldvar + newvar
      oldvar = newvar - oldvar

    Next x

cells(1,1) = series
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Slighly different using an array, so can output array if desired.

```
Sub Looping()

Dim a(19) As Long
Dim sOut As String
Dim newvar As Long

series=1
newvar = 1

For x = 1 To 20
    If x > 2 Then

        newvar = a(x - 3) + a(x - 2)
        a(x - 1) = newvar

    Else

        a(x - 1) = series

    End If

    sOut = sOut & IIf(x > 1, ",", "") & CStr(newvar)


Next x

Range("a1").Value = sOut

End Sub
```